# Force XmlDocument to save empty elements with an explicit closing tag

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have the following code:

```
string PathName = "C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Documents\\Project";
string FileName = "settings.xml";

XmlDocument Settings = new XmlDocument(); 
Settings.Load(Path.Combine(PathName, FileName));

XmlNode KnowledgeNode = Settings.SelectSingleNode("/Config/Map/Knowledge");

XmlNode UsersNode = Settings.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Users", null);
XmlAttribute FileDirectory = Settings.CreateAttribute("FileDirectory");
FileDirectory.Value = UserSelectedFileDirectory;
UsersNode.Attributes.Append(FileDirectory);
KnowledgeNode.AppendChild(UsersNode);

Settings.Save(Path.Combine(PathName, FileName));
```

This results in my XML file containing `<Users FileDirectory="C:\data" />`
instead of `<Users FileDirectory="C:\data" ></Users>` as I want.

How do I create the end element? I've given it a Google and I can't find much. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are three ways to force XmlDocument.Save to output a separate end tag for an empty XmlElement instead of an empty, self-closing tag.

### Method 1

Insert an empty whitespace node inside the element:

```
UsersNode.AppendChild(Settings.CreateWhitespace(""));
```

Here's the output:

```
<Users FileDirectory="C:\data"></Users>
```

### Method 2

Set the [XmlElement.IsEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the element to **false**:

```
((XmlElement)UsersNode).IsEmpty = false;
```

Note that with this method, the default XML formatting settings will insert a line break between the start tag and the end tag. Here's the output:

```
<Users FileDirectory="C:\data">
</Users>
```

### Method 3

Derive a custom XmlTextWriter that forwards all WriteEndElement calls to WriteFullEndElement:

```
public class CustomXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public CustomXmlTextWriter(string fileName)
        : base(fileName, Encoding.UTF8)
    {
        this.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        this.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var writer = new CustomXmlTextWriter(Path.Combine(PathName, FileName)))
{
    Settings.Save(writer);
}
```

This method might require less code overall if you have a lot of empty elements in your document.

As with Method 2, the default XML formatting settings will insert a line break between the start tag and end tag of each empty element.