# Attributes via XElement in C#_List of objects

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

I have a class "WsReferenceValue" that contains a list of other class "Characteristic" ,and the class Characteristic has a property another class "Definition",this is my code:

```
  public class WsReferenceValue
  {
     [DataContract]
     public class WsReferenceValue : WsEntitiesDimension
     {
        public List<Characteristic> listCharacteristic { get; set; }       
     }
     [DataContract]
     public class Characteristic
     {      
          [DataMember]      
           public Definition definition { get; set; } 
     }
     [Serializable]   
     public class Definition
     {
          [XmlAttribute]
           public int id;
           [XmlAttribute]
           public string name;
      }
 }
```

**My code:**

```
 WsReferenceValue referenceV = new WsReferenceValue();
 List<Characteristic> ListFinalDynamic = new List<Characteristic>();
 foreach (var finalCharac in listeCharactresticFinal)
 {
                var lstChars = new Characteristic()
                        {
                            Definition = new Definition()
                            {
                                id = Dimension.ID,
                                name = Dimension.Name
                            }
                        };                          
             ListFinalDynamic.Add(lstChars);                    
            referenceV.listCharacteristic = ListFinalDynamic;    
}
```

And I get this result:

```
 <WsReferenceValue>                     
    <listCharacteristic>
                <Characteristic>
                    <Definition>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <name>COMPANY</name>
                    </Definition>
                </Characteristic>

                <Characteristic>
                    <Definition>
                        <id>71</id>
                        <name>COUNTRY</name>
                    </Definition>
                </Characteristic>

                <Characteristic>
                    <Definition>
                        <id>45</id>
                        <name>CURRENCY</name>
                    </Definition>
                </Characteristic>
  </listCharacteristic>
```

And my goal is to get all list of Characteristic for one Reference with this format : (every Characteristic with attributes)

```
 <WsReferenceValue>                     
    <listCharacteristic>
                <Characteristic>
                    <Definition id=1 name="COMPANY" />                        
                </Characteristic>

                <Characteristic>
                    <Definition id=71 name="COUNTRY" />
                </Characteristic>

                <Characteristic>
                    <Definition id=45 name="CURRENCY" />                      
                </Characteristic>
  </listCharacteristic>
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270479/force-xmldocument-to-save-empty-elements-with-an-explicit-closing-tag

Comment: Thanks @JayakumarThangavel for your reply, 
but still not very clear ,because it is different from my objectif

Comment: How are you serializing to XML?  Your c# data models have a mix of `XmlSerializer` attributes and data contract attributes so it isn't clear

Comment: @dbc I don't serialize,I didin't do anything for the serializing.
The WCF runtime is serializing the results for me

Comment: Then you *probably* want [DataContract XML serialization and XML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4858798/3744182).  WCF uses the data contract serializer by default which doesn't support XML attributes, so you need to switch to `XmlSerializer` by applying `[XmlSerializerFormat]` to your service or operations contract.  If you were to share a [mcve] showing the service & operations contracts we could say for sure.

Comment: Thanks  a lot @dbc, I understand very well now the confusion,
Ok I will try your purpose,thanks

Comment: @IngTun2018 - did that work?  If not can you share an updated [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks, @dbc , in fact I modify the concept of my problem: first I don't work with xmlserializer,I work only with DataContractSerializer so I delete Definition Class, and then I add list xelement into one xelement ,and I get my result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  fact to resolve my problem: I modify the concept: first I don't work with XMLSerializer,I work only with DataContractSerializer so I delete Definition Class, and then I add list xelement into one xelement ,and I get my result,

My WsReferenceValue  class:

```
  [DataContract]
 public class WsReferenceValue : WsEntitiesDimension
 { 
    [DataMember]
    public XElement listCharacteristic {get ; set;}
}
```

The implementation:

```
WsReferenceValue referenceV = new WsReferenceValue();
foreach (var finalCharac in listeCharactresticFinal)
{    
  var XelementTemp = new XElement("ReferenceValue",
      new XAttribute("Name", refVal.Name),
      new XAttribute("Id", refVal.ID)); 

      referenceV.listCharacteristic.Add(XelementTemp);                  
 }
```

And I get my result exactly that I want it :

```
<listCharacteristic>
        <ReferenceValues xmlns="">
            <ReferenceValue Name="CC" Id="1"  />
            <ReferenceValue Name="S9999" Id="4" "0"/>
            <ReferenceValue Name="EE45" Id="5" />  
        </ReferenceValues>
</listCharacteristic>
```