# How to add a new node to an existing xml? using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I am trying to add a new node to an existing xmldocument as a root node, this is the code I have:

```
public XmlDocument FunctionG()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlResponse = ExecuteGet();
        XmlDocument xmlOperacion = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode aux;
        
        XmlNodeList nodeListCustom1 = xmlResponse.SelectNodes("/nodes/node/children/node[@ciType='Mabe_Operation']");
        
        aux = nodeListCustom1[0];
       
        XmlNodeList children2 = aux.SelectNodes("dimension");
        aux.RemoveChild(children2[0]);
        XmlNodeList children3 = aux.SelectNodes("dimension");
        aux.RemoveChild(children3[0]);
        XmlNodeList children4 = aux.SelectNodes("dimension");
        aux.RemoveChild(children4[0]);

        aux = nodeListCustom1[0];
        XmlNodeList children = aux.SelectNodes("children");

        aux.RemoveChild(children[0]);

       
        xmlOperacion.LoadXml(aux.OuterXml);
        
      
        XmlNode root = xmlOperacion.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode elem = xmlOperacion.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"nodes","");
        root.InsertAfter(elem, root.FirstChild);


        return xmlOperacion;

    }
```

The return returns the following:

```
<node>
<nodes/>
</node>
```

But I need it this way:

```
<nodes>
<node></node>
</nodes>
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Comment: What's your actual starting XML? And how would you like it to look?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Force XmlDocument to save empty elements with an explicit closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45270479/3744182).   Demo of setting `elem.IsEmpty = false;` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270649/3744182) by [Michael Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127114/michael-liu) here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pOqpEE.  If this doesn't answer your question, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] (with the input XML and required output) and we can re-open the question.